# how to manage data for view immediately after database file is imported into web application?

Tags: android, mysql, database, web

My title might have explained you a lot. But still I explain you in a use case way. In my web I have a database file that I insert data using form. I know, it is possible to see the data easily. After that, I export the same database file into my work station and then from there I import the file to android application. That database file is used for CRUD operations. When everything is done the same file is again imported to the web app and **merge** the two database files (web app database file and android database file) to be one and **manage** for the views of data.

Now, the question is that am I able to see the data from that **merged** file immediately after I import. When I import database file to web app, two files **merge** to one and then only data can be viewd. I can merge the two database files by coding  but for the view is the system responsible? Or, how can I do it fast? I mean I import file and after that I want to see changes of data in my view of web app.

I hope some one lead me to right direction. Only logical answer is required. Please do not suggest me another way to do because this is the only one way I want to do. Thanks in advance :)!!

Comment: Don't do heavy computing in UI thread. Use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) instead. Merge your files on `doInBackground` method, update your view on `onPostExecute` or on `onProgressUpdate`.

Comment: @interlude I am sorry you misunderstood me. I am doing in web app(PHP). I already have android app.

Comment: If you want to create server-to-client callback after updating DB you should either using some library for this (e.g. SignalR on ASP.NET and SignalA on client side, I don't know PHP solutions) or make repeated (with low delay) requests to server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope **Server-sent events** will be more opt in your criteria. (ie) Whenever you have a database update in your server side (using code or any), you need to trigger a "**Server-sent event**" so that it will be sent to your clients and make them request for view update or directly update through the trigger message.
Please check this QA for more clarification.
[Server-sent events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14564903/server-sent-events-and-php-what-triggers-events-on-the-server)